# error: Reverting is not possible because you have unmerged files

Tags: git, git-revert

When trying to revert a specific commit in git, I'm getting this error:

```
$ git revert aaaf93201a28a57d540d633b1b723b8e513a47ed
error: Reverting is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm '
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: revert failed
```

Is this about merge conflicts? But why does it say "unmerged files" in that case?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to revert to the previous state of your work  do:`git merge --abort`

Comment: Thanks. This was the easiest solution for my case.

Answer (score 3):

It is about merge conflicts, from some merge you attempted before. The unmerged files are the files where the merge conflict happened.

As stated in the error message, you should take care of these files and the contained conflicts before you do anything else. One additional option is to do a hard reset - only attempt this if you know what you're doing.

Comment: While true, this seems to gloss over the big issue with my understanding or git.  I attempt a merge, it has conflicts, I attempt to revert "git revert HEAD".  I want the branch I'm on to go back to the state it was before I merged.    Why would the merge conflicts matter in any way?

Answer (score 3):

In historical order, apply these commands:

```
git reset --hard <commit-id>
git push -f origin <branch-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run git status to better understand what is happening to your working branch or environment.

As written in the status, the best option is to run the command below to clean the previous attempt:

`git revert --abort`

With that, you are able to work in your branch as before.
There are two easy options.

1. To accept the changes as it is in the commit reverted:

`git revert <hashID> --strategy-option theirs`

2. Or to keep the changes that came later than the reverted commit:

`git revert <hashID> --strategy-option ours`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).